# Eclipse automatically start server after clean, how turn off?

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I use eclipse luna and glassfish 3.1, after server clean(server if off) server automatically turn on, I try to find some configuration but without results. I need solution for change this behaviour to run(turn on) server only on my will.

Thanks for advance.